# Remove first line/s from appended text

Tags: c#, user-interface, richtextbox

I struggle with my richtextbox in Visual Studio. I append the communication from serial interface (uart).

But after ~1000 lines I want to remove the first line/s.

But how should this work?

I tried:

```
this.richTextBox_message.Text.Remove(0, 1000);      // doesn't work
                                                    // would be bad solution, because i want to remove lines and not chars,
this.richTextBox_message.Select(0, 100);
this.richTextBox_message.SelectedText.Remove(1);    // doesn't work
```

Comment: WinForms? WPF? WebForms? MVC?

Comment: I’d do this with a listbox; easier to remove items

Comment: Since strings are immutable, you _always_ have to assign the modified value back to `richTextBox_message.Text`.

Answer (score 1):

**Compact version**

```
string text = this.richTextBox_message.Text;
this.richTextBox_message.Text = text.Substring(text.IndexOf('\n') + 1, text.Length - text.IndexOf('\n')-1);
```

**Explanation**

Since `strings` are `immutable`, we must create a new `string` without the first line and set the textbox's text to that.

Lets first grab a copy of the text so that we don't have to write `this.richTextBox_message.Text` all the time.

```
string text = this.richTextBox_message.Text;
```

We can use the `Substring` method to grab a version of the string without the first line. In order to do so, we have to know where to start and how many characters we want to grab. `Substring(int index, int length)`.

We can use `IndexOf` to find the first occurrence of a line delimiter character in the text. That will be exactly where the line ends. We then want to add 1 as to not include the line delimiter in our new text.

```
int startIndex = text.Substring(text.IndexOf('\n') + 1;
```

Now we need to find the length of the text we want to get. That's simple - we want all the text from the startIndex we just found, to the end of the text. We can subtract the startIndex from the text length to get the length we want.

```
int length = text.Length - startIndex;
```

Now we can get the new string.

```
string newValue = text.Substring(startIndex, length);
```

Finally write it back to the text property.

```
this.richTextBox_message.Text = newValue;
```

Comment: it works, but i lose all my text settings (some lines are colored)

Comment: You'll have to reapply them. You're probably better off not using a `richTextBox` here. Go with a listbox, that will also make it a lot easier to delete the first line. If you do have to use a text like component I recommand you use AvalonEdit, it's a lot easier to color/highlight text and it will retain the colors after you remove a line. https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit

Comment: Can you add some explanation to that code such that others can learn from it?

Comment: fstam, that is brilliant! Exemplary to other SO users!

Answer (score 0):

```
richTextBox1.Lines = richTextBox1.Lines.Skip(1).Take(richTextBox1.Lines.Length -1).ToArray();
```

Comment: it works, but i lose all my text settings (some lines are colored)

Comment: try this:`richTextBox1.Select(0, richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(1)); // select the first line
            richTextBox1.SelectedText = "";`